# Google Picker using Scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js, google-picker

I'd like to use **Google Picker** in my **Scala.js** app. I need to convert this [example](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#hiworld) somehow.

There are two main questions:

The first, how can I load and use https://apis.google.com/js/api.js in my **Scala.js** code to use `gapi` object?

```
gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
```

The second, after a picker will be loaded, how can I access to the `google.picker` object to create the picker?

```
var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for any other JavaScript API, you can basically access it with a dynamically typed API using `js.Dynamic` or with a (possibly hand-written) typed facade.

In this case, I'd recommend the dynamic API for the first part:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import js.Dynamic.{global => g, literal => lit}

g.gapi.load("auth", lit(callback = onAuthApiLoad))
g.gapi.load("picker", lit(callback = onPickerApiLoad))
```

and a static API for the second part:

```scala
@js.native
@JSName("google.picker.PickerBuilder")
class PickerBuilder() extends js.Object {
  // here you can declare methods and fields of PickerBuilder
}

val picker = new PickerBuilder()
```